# Can Xero be linked to rental car software to transfer data?

Tags: xero-api

[image]

I want to complete the content circled in red, which is to associate our car rental software with Xero to transmit data, and transmit the order content of each customer, such as order number, amount, platform profit, etc. to In Xero, how to use code to implement this function? Does Xero have a corresponding API that can be called?

I registered a xero account, and tried to operate according to the xeroAPI documentation, but I still have no idea